# Convert DF variable into multiple string variables not in the df (code Example included)

Tags: r, tidyverse

Having a df such as this:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), 
               V2 = c("Cat,Dog","Fish,Bird", "Cat, Fish, Bird", "Cat", "Dog, Bird", "Owl, Dog")), 
               class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

I filter by an specific value, say 1:

```
df <- df %>% filter(V1 == 1)
```

How can I save the results of V2 in multiple string variables (not in the df),

```
say V2_1 = "Cat" and V2_1 = "Dog"
```

Note that when dealing with V1 == 3 now I have 3 variables V2_1,V2_2,V2_3.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string on `","` and get vector.

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- df %>% filter(V1 == 1)
tmp <- unlist(strsplit(df$V2, ','))
```

If you want data as separate variables like `V2_1` , `V2_2` you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(tmp), paste0('V2_', seq_along(tmp))), .GlobalEnv)
```